# SQLite-CursorIndexOutofBound Exception-Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

**DBAdapter.java**

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

                        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_FIRSTNAME
                                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MIDDLENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_MAIL_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CONFIRM
                                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_DATE_OF_BIRTH
                                + " INTEGER NOT NULL "
                                + ");");

                    }

public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName) {

                Cursor cursor = mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE,null,KEY_USERNAME+" =?",new String[]{userName},null,null,null);
                if (cursor.getCount() < 1) // UserName Not Exist
                    return "NOT EXIST";
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String password = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("KEY_PASSWORD"));
                return password;

            }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    String stored_password = dbadapter.getSinlgeEntry(username);
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "The stored password is" + stored_password);
                        if(password.equals(stored_password))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"It is logging in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Profile_view.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Either username or password in invalid",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
```

**Logcat:**

```
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:419)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:117)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:31)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.example.signup.DBAdapter.getSinlgeEntry(DBAdapter.java:177)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.example.signup.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3100)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11644)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-06 16:05:47.682: E/AndroidRuntime(584):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have 3 complete `entries(firstname,middlename,lastname..)` in my table. And all the 
username already exists in the database but it says that `CursorIndexOutOfBoundException`.
 I have also moved the cursor to first position.

Comment: @laalto,Sorry to tell ya this but i am completely new to coding and stuffs so could you be a lil more specific as to where i should add SELECT * . Thanks anyways.

Comment: I will post a image version of my database. How do i do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KEY_PASSWORD` is your constant that defines the key column name, not the column name itself.

Replace

```
String password = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("KEY_PASSWORD"));
```

with

```
String password = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_PASSWORD));
```

Comment: I have edited it as you said. "KEY_PASSWORD" is replaced with KEY_PASSWORD. But i am still getting the same error and when i try to print the storedpassword,it returns as NOTEXIST. How is that possible ? I have entries in the table.  Thanks for taking the time and looking at the code. Much appreciated.

Comment: Error is gone in the logcat, thanks to you. But stored_password still returns NOT EXISTS !! Its really weird.

Comment: Fyi, I've deleted my answer since having null as the projection/result columns paremeter in the mDB.query call doesn't appear to be the issue...

Comment: Thanks NigelK. Appreciate you taking the effort.

Comment: It's rather hard to say if this code should return any record without knowing your data and what you're passing... Maybe you should open a separate question to keep one problem only in one question.

Comment: I believe the issue is due to the line if (cursor.getCount() < 1)
                    return "NOT EXIST";

Comment: But aint sure about it. It always returns NOT EXIST no matter how much ever record are present in the database.

Comment: You can comment out this line and see what happens.

Comment: I've tried it already but it goes back to CursorOutOfBoundException.

Comment: Which means you don't have any records in the cursor.

Comment: But i do have all the details. I am getting the firstname,middlename,lastname,username,passwords,mail ids etc from the user and it is stored in the same database. How can it be empty ? I am able to view the database content in SQLite Database Browser. This is really crazy.

Comment: I'm not sure without seeing it. But I strongly suggest that you open a new question and put all the details in there - it will be better for you and for this site.

Comment: Thanks Szymon. Will do that. Cheers.